# Using "like how" vs. "just as" after a comma in a comparison

Tags: comparisons, as-like

In a sentence comparing two related ideas, it strikes me as strange to say ____________________, like how ____________________.

For example,

> The car was painted when it was old, like how the house was painted
>   when it was old.

Is it just a matter of preference to use "just as" instead?

> The car was painted when it was old, just as the house was painted
>   when it was old.

The latter sounds more correct/natural to me, but is there a grammatical issue involved? Are both forms acceptable?

Comment: There might be instances when *like how* worked and this isn't one of them. By contrast *just as* works here and should also work in place of *like how* anywhere.

It’s almost true that both mean *in the same way that* but  *almost* doesn’t mean *always*.

Further, *like how* is just plain ugly.

Comment: Yes, I feel the same way. I was doing some editing, and wanted to justify replacing the author's use of _like how_ with _just as_ with a better reason than simply a different writing style. I haven't found a case of _like how_ that I liked, though!

Answer (score -1):

I would think that it is more natural to express similarity using a Germanic word which meant 'similar' for ever than to do it using a Latin borrowing which originally had to do with law.

Comment: Really, 250904? Could you clarify that?